# How do I use Get-PhysicalExtent on Get-PhysicalDisk?

Tags: powershell, automation, storage-spaces

No matter which server I try the PowerShell docs for Get-PhysicalExtent on, nothing works.  I've documented this as a bug on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/514  (I have no idea why it does not work, since I'm not experienced with this API or Windows Storage Spaces or Storage Management API).

The following is the error I get:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-physicaldisk

FriendlyName            SerialNumber    MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
------------            ------------    --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
Samsung SSD 860 EVO 4TB S3YNNB0KA01262B SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
Crucial_CT1050MX300SSD1 1652152B887B    SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 978.09 GB


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-physicaldisk -FriendlyName "Samsung SSD 860 EVO 4TB"

FriendlyName            SerialNumber    MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage          Size
------------            ------------    --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----          ----
Samsung SSD 860 EVO 4TB S3YNNB0KA01262B SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 3.64 TB


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalExtent -PhysicalDisk (get-physicaldisk -FriendlyName "Samsung SSD 860 EVO 4TB")
Get-PhysicalExtent : Not Supported
Activity ID: {7ba2cd2e-bd23-4b54-b4dc-c6a9ae118492}
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PhysicalExtent -PhysicalDisk (get-physicaldisk -FriendlyName "Sam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-PhysicalExtent], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 1,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand,Get-PhysicalExtent
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: My guess would be that the operation is not supported because the physical disk you're querying is neither dynamic nor part of a storage pool.  What do Get-VirtualDisk and Get-StorageTier return?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Get-VirtualDisk returns information about Virtual Disks, and I don't  have any.  Get-VirtualDisk returns 0 disks in AWS and 0 disks on my local machine.  Get-PhysicalDisk returns the same disks that are in the Windows "create and format disk partition" GUI.  All I'm looking to do is automate to check that I correctly configured disks to use 64KB extents.  That said, Get-StorageTier also returns nothing.  Why would I need to query something dynamic or part of a storage pool in order to find out its physical extent?

Comment: My workaround is the following: Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "FileSystem='NTFS'" | Select-Object Name, Label, BlockSize | Format-Table -AutoSize   ---- but it still does not answer the question as to why I get "Not Supported".  I tried to find the source code on GitHub (hoping it was open source) but no such luck - GitHub source code search returned a bunch of forks of the documentation

Comment: FYI git hub bug reports for Windows Powershell are ignored.  The git hub repo is for Powershell Core which is not the same as Windows Powershell.  Bug reporting for Windows Powershell is on UserVoice.

Comment: @colyn1337 thanks, but this is for the MS Docs, not Windows PowerShell.  And yeah, I'm aware - PowerShell is an absolute mess and I have even tried coaching some of their employees into writing better code b/c PowerShell is an absolute MESS of a language - core modules with functions that are 1,000s of lines ,long that dont return proper error messages, that fail their own lint tools all over the place, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "extent" is overloaded in Windows.  [One meaning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/clusters-and-extents) is a run of contiguous clusters, and this seems to be the meaning you're thinking of, though technically the number you're looking for is called the *cluster size* or the *block size* rather than the extent size.

The *other* meaning, which appears to be largely or entirely undocumented, is the area of space on a pooled disk that contains one fragment of the data for a [storage space](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/overview).  An extent in this sense may also be referred to as an "allocation" or as a "slab".

**The `Get-PhysicalExtent` command refers to the second of these two meanings.**

So the short version is that the command doesn't do what you thought it did, and it is giving you a "not supported" error because the request isn't meaningful for basic disks, only for disks in storage pools.  I see from the comments that you have already figured out the correct command, copied here for the benefit of future readers:

```
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "FileSystem='NTFS'" | Select-Object Name, Label, BlockSize | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The documentation could certainly be clearer.  I was only able to find references to this use of the word "extent" in Microsoft blog posts, not in the official documentation, though I believe I've read it in the official documentation at some point in the past, though probably in the context of dynamic disks rather than storage spaces.  To make certain that I was interpreting the command correctly in the absence of clear documentation to that effect, I tested it; read on if you want more detail, though since you're not using storage spaces you may find it uninteresting.

---

On my Windows 10 machine, with a spare USB disk attached and configured as a basic disk, I got the same error message you did:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalExtent -PhysicalDisk (Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1")
Get-PhysicalExtent : Not Supported
Activity ID: {45d91cf6-475f-4851-98be-6dd199e54c34}
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PhysicalExtent -PhysicalDisk (Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "ATA ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-PhysicalExtent], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 1,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand,Get-P
   hysicalExtent
```

I then deleted the partition and used the disk to [create a new storage spaces pool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces) and reran the command(*):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalExtent -PhysicalDisk (Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 SCSI Disk Device")


ColumnNumber          : 0
CopyNumber            : 0
Flags                 : 0x0000000000000000
OperationalDetails    :
OperationalStatus     :
PhysicalDiskOffset    : 0
PhysicalDiskUniqueId  : 5000000000000001
ReplacementCopyNumber :
Size                  : 268435456
StorageTierUniqueId   :
VirtualDiskOffset     : 0
VirtualDiskUniqueId   : CD6F8CC06A09E911907918DBF22A4387
PSComputerName        :
```

No longer unsupported, but not much data there: unsurprising, since I only created the pool without adding a storage space.  There is a single 256MB extent (sometimes referred to as a "slab", e.g., [see here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/11/21/deep-dive-pool-in-spaces-direct/)) which I believe contains the database for the storage pool.

After adding a storage space, we see additional extents:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalExtent -PhysicalDisk (Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 SCSI Disk Device")


ColumnNumber          : 0
CopyNumber            : 0
Flags                 : 0x0000000000000000
OperationalDetails    :
OperationalStatus     :
PhysicalDiskOffset    : 0
PhysicalDiskUniqueId  : 5000000000000001
ReplacementCopyNumber :
Size                  : 268435456
StorageTierUniqueId   :
VirtualDiskOffset     : 0
VirtualDiskUniqueId   : CD6F8CC06A09E911907918DBF22A4387
PSComputerName        :

ColumnNumber          : 0
CopyNumber            : 0
Flags                 : 0x0000000000000000
OperationalDetails    :
OperationalStatus     :
PhysicalDiskOffset    : 268435456
PhysicalDiskUniqueId  : 5000000000000001
ReplacementCopyNumber :
Size                  : 268435456
StorageTierUniqueId   :
VirtualDiskOffset     : 0
VirtualDiskUniqueId   : 9FA0BECD7ADBE943A073F4D303561F41
PSComputerName        :

ColumnNumber          : 0
CopyNumber            : 0
Flags                 : 0x0000000000000000
OperationalDetails    :
OperationalStatus     :
PhysicalDiskOffset    : 536870912
PhysicalDiskUniqueId  : 5000000000000001
ReplacementCopyNumber :
Size                  : 268435456
StorageTierUniqueId   :
VirtualDiskOffset     : 214479929344
VirtualDiskUniqueId   : 9FA0BECD7ADBE943A073F4D303561F41
PSComputerName        :

ColumnNumber          : 0
CopyNumber            : 0
Flags                 : 0x0000000000000000
OperationalDetails    :
OperationalStatus     :
PhysicalDiskOffset    : 805306368
PhysicalDiskUniqueId  : 5000000000000001
ReplacementCopyNumber :
Size                  : 268435456
StorageTierUniqueId   :
VirtualDiskOffset     : 3221225472
VirtualDiskUniqueId   : 9FA0BECD7ADBE943A073F4D303561F41
PSComputerName        :
```

Here we see the original slab containing the database plus another three slabs, all associated with the new virtual disk and each with different physical and virtual disk offsets.  So the command is working, at least on my machine, it just doesn't do what you wanted it to.

(*) For some reason, adding the disk to the storage pool changed the disk's friendly name.

---

For completeness, it should be noted that some versions of Windows provide a now-deprecated technology known as [dynamic disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks).  Dynamic disks offered some of the same functionality as Storage Spaces.  The area of space on a dynamic disk that stored a fragment of the data belonging to a virtual disk was also sometimes referred to as an "extent".

At present, I am not sure whether or not the Get-PhysicalExtent command supports dynamic disks in addition to pooled disks.  If I get a chance later on I'll try it out and update the post accordingly.

Comment: The more I encounter Storage Spaces (through side reading), the more I think there is a bunch of programmers at Microsoft who simply fail at filesystem design.   Maybe I'm wrong.  RAIFS and UnionFS on linux seem much simpler, albeit without the nicety of PowerShell's object-orientedness to query the disk config.